# setAlpha for RemoteViews problem

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm making an appwidget, and there's a bitmap on the widget of which I want to change it's transparency.

In the service I have:

```
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.myWidget);

remoteView.setInt(R.id.widgetPNG, "setAlpha", 50);
```

But it doesn't work. The emulator shows "Problem loading widget" on the home screen.
I'm pretty sure everything else is fine cos when i changed the line to change it's imageResource it runs perfectly: `remoteView.setInt(R.id.widgetPNG, "setImageResource", R.drawable.anotherPNG).`

Can anyone help me? I've been stuck with this for a week...

Answer (score 10):

Am fraid you can only call `setInt()` and friends on APIs which are marked with the `@RemotableViewMethod` annotation in the Android source code ([example](http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/View.java&q=RemotableViewMethod&d=4&l=7375)). Afraid `setAlpha()` is not one of them.

Maybe you could have two background images, a transparent one and a non-transparent one...

Comment: Two images is not an option for me, as what I want is to fade out the image gradually say, 10% every hour.

Comment: How else can I change the transparency of an image in a widget?

Comment: Use 9 images? You could try creating your own view class which has a public setAlpha(int) with the @android.view.RemotableViewMethod annotation. Not sure it'll work, but worth a shot. You'd need to include a file declaring RemotableViewMethod in the android.view package.

Comment: Where should I create the class?

Comment: In your project. Something like class MyView extends View { ... @android.view.RemotableViewMethod public void setAlphaPublic(int alpha) { setAlpha(alpha); } ... }

Comment: Tried it, custom class don't work. Changed to the 9 images way (14 in my case). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Update: The limitation this answer refers to is fixed on Android API 31

Answer (score 8):

Set image in a src of imageview in XML. In java:

```
 if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) > Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR_MR1) {
     rViews.setInt(R.id.imageview, "setAlpha", 30);
 }
```

try this one this support only available above 2.1

Comment: Also note that `setAlpha(int)` was deprecated and replaced with `setImageAlpha(int)` in API 16.

Comment: The docs for setImageAlpha: "int: the alpha value that should be applied to the image (between 0 and 255 inclusive, with 0 being transparent and 255 being opaque)"