# RemoteViews.setInt() not working on Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm using the `setInt()` method of `RemoteViews` to change the alpha of my appwidget's background. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setInt%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) tells that the method is available since API level 3, unfortunately it fails on an Android 1.6 emulator and also on a Samsung Galaxy S device with Android 2.1-update 1. So, what Android versions currently support this method and should I use it at all, as it seems too risky to implement?

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313274/setalpha-for-remoteviews-problem

Comment: Particularly the answer given by Reuben Scratton, if you are seeking a backwards-compatible option...

Comment: @seanhodges, I've seen it, but it doesn't answer my question properly: is there a mistake in the Android docs and where can I find the correct documentation on the setInt() method?

Comment: OK, found a solution for this one. As it turns out, the setInt() method for a "setAlpha" parameter is only available since Android 2.2, when the setAlpha() method received the @RemotableViewMethod annotation.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. As you say, it's the "setAlpha" parameter, not the setInt() method, that is the issue.